# how to redirect to a Action which has a post method in play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-2.11

```
case class ResetPasswordJsonValidation (id : String ,email : String)

object ResetPasswordJsonValidation {

  implicit val resetPasswordRead : Reads[ResetPasswordJsonValidation]= (
        (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
        (JsPath \ "id").read(id))
(ResetPasswordJsonValidation.apply _)
}

def resetPassword = Action {
    request =>
      request.body.asJson.get.validate[ResetPasswordJsonValidation].fold(

          resetPassword =>
            {
              log.info("id is {}" ,resetPassword.id)
              log.info("email id is {}" ,resetPassword.email)
            }
)
}
```

in routes file

```
POST   /direct-user/reset-password                      controllers.DirectUserController.resetPassword
```

this is the curl file which i used to hit this route

```
#!/bin/bash

contentType="Content-type: application/json";

data='{  "id" : "54d3732d-d728-40d3-ae63-b18ab6be8e70" ,
       "email":"bob@example.com"}';
echo "    "
echo "------------------   Sending Data   ------------------"
echo "    "
echo "Content-Type : " $contentType
echo "Data : " $data


echo "    "
echo "------------------     Response     ------------------" 
echo "    "
echo "    "



curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data "$data" http://localhost:9000//direct-user/reset-password
```

now i want to do this with code means i have an Action `A` in which i need to redirect to `resetPassword`Action i don't know how to do that 
please help me

```
def A = Action {
    var email:String="bob@example.com"
    var id:String="54d3732d-d728-40d3-ae63-b18ab6be8e70"
    Redirect(routes.DirectUserController.resetPassword())//how can i send email and id parameter to resetPassword as its getting from curl file  
  }
```

please help

Comment: Could you please tell why you want to do this rather than have the user post to that url directly?

Comment: because in action A i am blocking the user after 5 unsuccessful attempts then he/she will redirect to reset password Action i omitted the code for simplicity

Comment: is the A action a POST itself?

Comment: You may want to try using a 307 code. This is an interesting read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99966

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirect you can directly call that method instead of via routes object,

return directController.resetPassword()

Because the context object (Request , Response, Session are local to that thread so you can get those parameters from request object )